# Why is the Soundcloud API's `online` field always `false`?

Tags: soundcloud

When I check the SoundCloud API with `GET: http://api.soundcloud.com/users/169322002`, I always see `"online": false`.

```
{
  "id": 169322002,
  "kind": "user",
  "permalink": "yrxtnnjdtv98",
  "username": "User 293464893",
  "last_modified": "2015/08/19 20:47:45 +0000",
  "uri": "https://api.soundcloud.com/users/169322002",
  "permalink_url": "http://soundcloud.com/yrxtnnjdtv98",
  "avatar_url": "https://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-000164082810-4glxxg-large.jpg",
  "country": null,
  "first_name": "",
  "last_name": "",
  "full_name": "",
  "description": null,
  "city": null,
  "discogs_name": null,
  "myspace_name": null,
  "website": null,
  "website_title": null,
  "track_count": 0,
  "playlist_count": 0,
  "online": false,
  "plan": "Free",
  "public_favorites_count": 3,
  "followers_count": 0,
  "followings_count": 0,
  "subscriptions": [],
  "reposts_count": 20
}
```

Also when I check it with my account. There is always false.

Why does `online` always return false?

Comment: I assume the user is actually online? It could be to do with caching. The API results likely don't return live data so it may take a while for the cache to clear when a user is online or not.

Answer (score 0):

The `online` field is no longer used due to having inaccurate information.  This field was deprecated many years ago and an explanation used to exist in [this help article](http://help.soundcloud.com/customer/portal/articles/1485216-where-did-who-s-online-go-) (which now 404s).